# How to show page loading spinner in my html page content using jquery mobile or jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, spinner, pageload

I want to show page loading spinner in my html page content using jquery mobile or jquery .i tried some coding in jquery and ajax. its not working ...is there any solution ..can anyone suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should help you to achieve that.

All of these basically show the same thing <sup>( making website with ajax loaded content and loading indicator. )</sup> with some differences.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp

Comment: any suggestions on how to do a fullscreen spinner version? Currently the defauly jqm spinner appears only inside a small rectangle in the middle of the screen. This leaves the entire page vulnerable to clicks by the user WHILE my loading process is underway. I would prefer that the spinner is displayed on top of a full-screen overlay (like the jqm 'popup') that blocks the rest of the content.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd My first idea was to just spread `.ui-loader` to cover the viewport, but that doesn't work since it is given a top value every time you scroll, to keep it centered vertically. This actually makes things very difficult. My second idea was to wrap another element around it and spread that to cover the whole viewport, but that doesn't work so well because then you'd have to control the visibility of that element separately from the `.ui-loader`. The easiest option is to go with what you got :)

Answer (score 1):

just use a .gif image. Just do a Google image search "spinner gif".
Then save the spinner.gif to ur local.  Use "visibility" to show and hide....

Procedure:-
1. Open Google.com

1. Click Image Search
2. "Enter Spinner.gif"  in search box
3. Click Search button

its done now you will find lot of gif image
download as your wish(Any .gif image fit for your app)
Store it in your local the use in html,

Answer (score 0):

```
///HTML CODE////
<div class="loader">
</div>
<button id="btn">
click 
</button>
<p>Processing - Please wait </p>

// CSS CODE ///
.loader {
  border: 16px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #1BB2AC;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/// JQUERY CODE ///
$('.loader').hide();
$('p').hide();
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('.loader').hide();
     $('p').hide()
      $('#btn').hide();
        }, 2000)
    $('p').show();
        $('.loader').show();
    $('#btn').hide();
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxpkumar/4kgupxeL/#&togetherjs=8rscNma3nL